# jQuery selection exclude certain elements

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have this code but was wondering how would I exclude certain divs like for example div id="foo"

Like this

```
$(document (except #foo) ).click(function() {
$("#re").animate({
  "margin-top": "0px"
}, 800);
$("#r").animate({
  "margin-top": "0px"
}, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:not` pseudo-selector...

```
$("div:not(#foo)");
```

That will select all divs, except the one with an ID of foo.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `target` of event object:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
   if ( $(event.target).closest('#foo').length ) return;
   // ... 
});
```

Comment: Isn't that *a bit* overkill, to assign a click handler to every single element on the page, and then check them when they're clicked?

Comment: @Archer It depends, I assumed OP wants to listen to every click on the document, please note that it doesn't assign a handler to each element, the handler is called by using event propagation. Otherwise using `not` selector/method makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I know that was a bit literal to say it assigns a handler to every element.  It just runs it on every element.  And at second read I can see why you may have got that impression from the question now.